# Ng Component withTypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I've built two components: *signup* and *signup-form*.

[image: Signup-form looks like this].

After filling up the form and clicking the Submit button I get:

[image: error]

I've searched through all the questions with similar problem and none of them helped me fix the blocker.

*Signup.component.html* has the sign-up form component:

```
(...)
<app-signup-form></app-signup-form>
(...)
```

*Signup-form.component.html*:

```
<form [formGroup]="mysignup">
  <div class="form-group">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" ngModel="name"  required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" formControlName="email" ngModel="email"  required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      Password:<br>
      <input type="password" formControlName="password" ngModel="password" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="signupUser()" />
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <pre>{{mysignup.value | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

*Signup-form.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Linking the form model to the form template
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup-form',
  templateUrl: './signup-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup-form.component.scss']
})
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {
  mysignup: FormGroup;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.mysignup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
  }
  signupUser($scope, $http) {
    this.mysignup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
  // debugger;
    $http.post('test.php', {
      'name': $scope.name,
      'email': $scope.email,
      'password': $scope.mysignup.password
    }).then(function(Response) {
      console.log('Data inserted successfully');
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Sorry! Data couldnt be inserted!');
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

I just want the data to arrive `test.php` because from there onward I know how to handle.

*How to fix this?*

Comment: :o  $scope with angular2?

Comment: `constructor(private $http: HttpClient) {}` should do the trick. However, why on earth are you  using `$scope` and `$http` in Angular 2+ code? That belongs to AngularJS (1.x)

Comment: that doesn't solve the issue... I've tried that before @lealceldeiro

Comment: @BárbaraPeres did you import the `HttpClientModule`?

Comment: yes, you can see that in the code

Comment: @BárbaraPeres No, I can't see it. In the import there is a `HttpClient` but not an **`HttpClientModule`**. Besides the `HttpClientModule` is usually imported in the app module, not in a component. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: i do have in app.module.ts: import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: @BárbaraPeres please see my updated answer. Did it work? Else, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have `http` in your code. Change your constructor to this:

First, import `http` like this:      `import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";`

Then declare a local variable named `http` in your constructor like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

**Also**, it's a standard practice to use **`http`** instead of `$http`.

**And** do NOT pass `$http` and `$scope` to `signupUser function`. Within `signupUser function` access the form values like this: 
 `this.formGroupName.controls['formControlName'].value`  (In your case `this.mysignup.controls['name'].value`).

Then, you can call the `signupUser` from html like:

```
 <button (click)="signupUser()">Sign UP<button>
```

You'll have to change your `post` call like this (NOTE: `http.post` returns an **Observable** so you'll have to subscribe to it like this):

```
this.http.post('test.php', {
  'name': this.mysignup.controls['name'].value,
  'email': this.mysignup.controls['email'].value,
  'password': this.mysignup.controls['password'].value
}).subscribe(function(Response) {
  console.log('Data inserted successfully');
}, function(error) {
  alert('Sorry! Data couldnt be inserted!');
  console.error(error);
});
```

Please note: It is advisable to write all the `HttpClient` related(`get`, `post`, etc..) codes separately in service file.

Comment: The OP is importing it like this: `import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";` and `constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }` didn't solve the issue. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084592/ng-component-withtypeerror-cannot-read-property-post-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment89157787_51084592)

Comment: @noobs it raises a problem with .then, observable

Comment: @BárbaraPeres see my updated answer. Issue with your existing code is that you are using `.then()` instead of `.subscribe()` as `http.post` returns an **`observable`** instead of a **`promise`**.

Comment: this is just testing atm. by using the code you provide and fixing 'name' and 'email to match 'password ( $scope.mysignup.password ) I get:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'mysignup' of undefined

Comment: @BárbaraPeres As earlier mentioned in my answer, please do not use `$scope` use `this.formGroupName.controls['formControlName'].value` instead. Also, updated my answer.

Comment: great help @noobs

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are too much in old Angular 1.x patterns there. The error comes from the line with `$http.post`, because you injected the $http service in the `signupUser` method. You will need to inject it into the constructor of your component class

```
constructor(protected $http: HttpClient) {}
```

and then access it in the class' methods with

```
this.$http.post(...)
```

*Don't forget to import **CommonModule** in the @Module declaring this component.*

More info about dependency injection in the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern

Also consider to overthink your variable naming, because the `$` sign is not used for this case in Angular 2+, and don't use `$scope`, but data bindings.

Comment: Would you update your question with the new code/error please?

Comment: Don't forget to import CommonModule in the @Module declaring this component.